# Python lxml extract value of span tags

Tags: python, html, lxml

I'm trying to get the values of the span tags from the sourcecode of a website. But I want only span tags which look like this:

```
<span>
   Test
</span>
```

And Not like this:

```
<span class="test">blabla</span>
```

My current codes looks like this:

```
test = tree.xpath('//span[@class]/text()')
```

Comment: To clarify: you only want `span` tags that have no other attributes?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Xpath, you can specify that the `span` elements should have no attributes using the predicate `not(@*)`:

```
from lxml import etree

x = '''<body>
<span>
   Test
</span>
<span class="test">blabla</span>
</body>'''

xml = etree.fromstring(x)
xml.xpath('//span[not(@*)]/text()')

# returns:
['\n   Test\n']
```